# Can i sort table rows into "buckets" in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data that looks like this:

```
---------------
VM | WriteRate
---------------
vm1   100
vm2   1000
vm3   500
vm4   750
vm5   200
```

What I need to do is sort these records into groups where the SUM of WriteRate, is equal or less than 1000

SO the result should be something like:

```
Bucket 1 = vm1,vm3
Bucket 2 = vm2
Bucket 3 = vm4,vm5
```

I'm wondering if this can be accomplished in MySQL? Or will I need to use some other language like PHP to do the sorting with some loops or something?

Comment: Why isn't vm3 and vm5 in a bucket ? and vm1 and vm4 in another ?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `GROUP_CONCAT`, but honestly, this is way easier to do in your application layer than in your database.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya a VM should only be in one bucket... it should not exist in more than one. (this exercise is for planning which datastore to replicate to based on throughput of the Vms, the solution should create create a map so that no datastore is over commited)